# Difference between “I will call you” and “I give you a call”?

Tags: expressions, word-usage

What is the difference between *I will call you* and *I give you a call*?

Comment: "I will call you" and "I will give you a call" mean the same thing.

Comment: Well one is proper English and one is not.

Comment: Rye Read which one is proper English?

Comment: You are on the wrong site. Check out [SE English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com) which may be suitable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you can't say "I give you a call". I gather you meant "I ***will*** give you a call".

As far as phone calls are concerned, there is little, if any, difference in meaning or register. However, the first sentence:

> I will call you.

is much more generic and, without proper context, may have meanings other than phone calls. For example, when you read

> Go to your room. I'll call you when dinner is ready.

You don't imagine any phones involved, whereas

> Go to your room. I'll give you a call when the dinner is ready

implies a strange situation when you make a phone call to someone in the same house.